# "Call for price" hook for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using this hook which works great when the product price field is empty, using "woocommerce_empty_price_html":

```
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'snaj_replace_text_with_call_for_price');
function snaj_replace_text_with_call_for_price() {
return _e('Call for price','admin_texts_xts-woodmart-options') ;
}
```

But I need the price not to be empty, and I'd like to make this work by looking for a category that I'd call "call-for-price".

I'm not a coder, but I guess it should look like something like that, using 'woocommerce_get_price_html':

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'snaj_replace_text_with_call_for_price');
function snaj_replace_text_with_call_for_price() {
$categories = array( 'call-for-price');
 if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', get_the_id() ) ) {
return _e('Call for price','admin_texts_xts-woodmart-options') ;
}
}
```

But it doesn't work !

With that code, the product in this category is acting as intended, but products out of this category are not showing prices anymore !

Does anyone have the solution to add the condition "if the product displays the category call-for-price" AND that "the price exists"?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed returning the price outside the condition. in filters hook, you must return a value from the filter.

It should be like that.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'snaj_replace_text_with_call_for_price', 100, 2 );
function snaj_replace_text_with_call_for_price( $price, $product ) {
    $categories = array( 'call-for-price');
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', get_the_id() ) ) {
        return __('Call for price','admin_texts_xts-woodmart-options') ;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: The only problem that I have now, is that it prints "Call for price" above the header. Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: You need to use __() instead of _e(). answer is updated.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank's a lot for your help !